# How can I match two words separated by multiple spaces in a given sentence using Regex in C++?

Tags: c++, regex

I have the sentences "This is the **best day** of my life" and "Here are the **best

     day** of my life"and "**best       day**". I wish to match "best" followed by "day" using regex, i.e the sentence should contain the expression "best day".Note that there can be any number of spaces between "best" and "day", however, **day** should come after **best**.

I wrote this regex - `(best)(\\s+)(day)` and used regex_match in C++ but it's not working. I'm not very familiar with Regex; could somebody guide me?

```
bool isValidBestDay(string str)
{
    string bestDay = "(best)(\\s+)(day)";
    regex bestDayMatch(suchThat, ECMAScript | icase);
    return regex_match(str, bestDayMatch);
}
```

The problem I'm facing on C++ is that if I have a string 'best day' it matches, but not if I have something like "this best day".
Thanks!

Comment: I reccomend this website to test and learn regex http://regexr.com/

Comment: Using ye olde regexes: `best  *day`

Comment: The character-classification regex is probably very wrong here.

Comment: It should work and as always reason could be somewhere else, so please edit your question to contain [mcve]. There  is a reason for that rule.

Comment: stackoverflow.com is not a tutoring site.

Comment: Your code is not complete nor verifiable. Click on that link and read the rule.

Comment: What's wrong with your regex? It works. Also, I would suggest [regex101](https://regex101.com) instead of regexr (I used to use regexr, but it doesn't offer as much support as regex101)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`regex_search`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_search) instead of [`regex_match`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_match), [since](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_search):

> regex_search will successfully match any subsequence of the given
>   sequence, whereas std::regex_match will only return true if the
>   regular expression matches the entire sequence.

Answer (score -2):

The regex you're looking for is

```
((best)\s*(day))
```

Goto this website http://regexr.com

In the `Expression` box put the regex I gave
and In the `Text` box put following examples, you'll understand.

ex.

`This is the best day of my life`

`This is the best     day of my life`

`This is the best not day of my life`

Comment: Great now try your regex against `My name is bestday`, does it match? Also, you should try to present the input/output in a more legible way. What will it catch, what will it not catch?

Comment: `\s+` is fine and prefered in this case, there is another issue in OPs code